# SQL Server 2005 - Add Milliseconds column onto DateTime column

Tags: sql, datetime, addition

How do i combine 2 column using SQL server 2005 ?

Problem is that The DateTime is stored in 1 column and the milliseconds is stored in another column.

I want to add the Milliseconds onto DateTime column to give it a more accurate DateTime.

I need to use this DateTime to query record accurate to milliseconds.

Any idea?

I need to replace DateTime with the added values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE [DateTime] >= '2011-04-12 12:00:00 AM'
AND [DateTime] <= '2011-05-25 3:35:04 AM'
```

and run the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first solve your problem:

```
SELECT DATEADD(millisecond,<milliscolumn>,<datetimecolumn>) from <table>
```

And then file a bug report that these should just be stored in one column anyway.

---

You can do this, based on your sample query, but note that this destroys the possibility of the server being able to use an index:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE
    DATEADD(millisecond,[MillisecondColumn],[DateTime]) between
        '2011-04-12T12:00:00' AND '2011-05-25T03:35:04'
```

If this is a large table, then indexes may be important. If you can't alter whatever's populating this data, you might want to add this calculation as a persisted computed column to this table, and then index and query against that.

Note that I've replaced your two comparisons with a single `BETWEEN`, and also adjusted the datetime strings so that they're not affected by regional settings.

Comment: I need to use the DateTime values as below.

    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLENAME 
    WHERE [DateTime] >= '2011-04-12 12:00:00 AM'
    AND [DateTime] <= '2011-05-25 3:35:04 AM'

How can i replace DateTime with the added milliseconds?

Comment: @overule - if you're going to add a more specific example, it may be better to edit it into your question, rather than (attempt) to add it as a comment to my answer

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Refer back to the question.

Comment: For DATEADD(millisecond,[MillisecondColumn],[DateTime])
What's millisecond? Is it the millisecond value?
and for [MillisecondColumn] that's the database column holding the millisecond value ?

Comment: @overrule - millisecond is literally those 10 characters, appearing unquoted. Yes, `[MilllisecondColumn]` is the name of the column in `TableName` that holds the number of milliseconds you want to add. [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) has many examples of how `DATEADD` is used.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (ColumnA + ColumnB) AS ColumnZ
FROM Table

might solve your problem.